# python regular expression module

Tags: python, regex

I have to read a text file line by line and extract some part of each line. I have a working code if the line I am reading is in the expected format but this is not always the case. There are errors in the file, i.e. some missing information or characters. So I want to skip these faulty lines. For this, I want to utilize `regular expression` module. I defined the regular expression I need. Lets say, `reg_exp_string` is going to be matched with the line I read. I want a full match, I do not want to searh some part of the text. If it is a full match return true, otherwise return false. The think is, I tried `re.match()` and it returns an object. I couldn't figure it out. What is the correct way to use it? It always returns an object if some part of the string matches with the regular expression. I want a full match only and get a boolean answer. How can I do this?

Comment: Regular expression Tutorial/How-To http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: This question shows absolutely no research effort on the part of the OP. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553

Comment: I am not researchin anything, I am just asking a question.

Comment: Please see the link Joel provided - it will show of some the expectations for posting questions on SO.

Comment: I read the document. anyways.. I request my account to be deleted. If you know the answer, just post it. I am clear about my question. of course, I read it and other documents. Still, could not find a thing about a full match. It either searches or matches a part of it. Is it that hard to show how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), `$` matches the end of a string. You can modify your regular expression to include `$` at the end. Example:

```
match_this = "abc12a" #expression you would like to match
dont_match_this = "abc12a9" #expression that returns partial matches from re.match
```

The old regular expression will match both `match_this` and `dont_match_this`:

```
old_reg_expr = "[a-z]+\d[a-z]+"
```

The new regular expression contains `$` and only returns a match if the string ends after the last element matched in the expression:

```
new_reg_expr = "[a-z]+\d[a-z]+$"
```

Alternatively, you could leave your old regular expression intact and just check to see if the ending position of the match is equal to the end of the string:

```
>>> m = re.match("[a-z]+\d[a-z]+", "abc12a9")
>>> m.end() == m.endpos
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for match objects is [a little further down](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects).

Answer (score -1):

`re.match()` should return a match object, unless there is no match, in which case it returns `None`:

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match

Comment: I would be thankful if an explanation for the downvotes could be provided.

Answer (score -1):

As documented in http://docs.python.org/library/re.html, match() will return a MatchObject is a match is found, None otherwise.

So, simply say:

```
for line in ... :
    m = your_regexp.match(line)
    if m:
        process(line)
```

Comment: If it matches at the begining, it returns an object but, What I need is whole text match.

Comment: @gokhan_ufl: You can check to see if `match.end() == match.endpos` to ensure that the match is for the whole string.

Comment: thanks. this is what I was looking for. actually the answer is shorter than the "read this document" posts. And it is really helping. This is the key element, I guess. Help people.

Comment: If you need it to match the whole line, make your regexp _anchored_, for example `^this matches a whole line$`. Also, if you _don't_ want it to be anchored by default to the beginning of the line, use `search()` instead of `match()`.